# Recognize simple digits with pytesser

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, pytesser

I'm learning OCR using `PyTesser` and `Tesseract`. As the first milestone, I want to write a tool to recognize captcha that simply consists of some digits. I read some tutorials and wrote such a test program.

```
from pytesser.pytesser import *
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageEnhance

im = Image.open("test.tiff")
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
text = image_to_string(im)
print "text={}".format(text)
```

I tested my code with the image below. But the result is `2(T?770`. And I've tested some other similar images as well, in 80% case the results are incorrect.

[image]

I'm not familiar with imaging processing. I've two questions here:

1. Is it possible to tell `PyTesser` to guess digits only?
2. I think the image is quite easy for human to read. If it is so difficult for `PyTesser` to read digits only image, is there any alternatives can do a better OCR?

Any hints are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is quite okay. It can recognize `207770`. The problem is at `pytesser` installation. The `Tesseract` in `pytesser` is out-of-date. You'd download a most recent version and overwrite corresponding files. You'd also edit `pytesser.py` and change

```
tesseract_exe_name = 'tesseract'
```

to

```
import os.path
tesseract_exe_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tesseract')
```

Comment: How did you know the Tesseract in pytesser is out-of-date?